# Como detener esta propagacion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

me han mandado este ejercicio en clases y tengo como 3 dias sin poder detener esta propagación, he intentado detener la propagación en todos lados y sin ningun resultado, la idea es que al clickear corazon, o el comentario en cada imagen, no se gatille el link padre (.meals_link) de todos los elementos... ojala me puedan guiar, he intentado con casi todos los selectores que se me ocurrieron `

```js
$(function(){

    $('button').on('click', 'i.fa-heart', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('.social__like').toggleClass('social__like--clicked');
  });

  $('button').on('click','i.fa-comment-alt', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('href'));
  });

  $('ul.social').on('click','li.social__element', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
  $('a').on('click','ul.social', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
  $('li.meals__meal').on('click','a', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/04.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/04.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>


<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/05.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/05.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/06.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/06.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/07.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/07.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/08.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/08.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/09.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/09.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/10.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/10.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: No he entendido muy bien tu problema, ¿lo que quieres es que el botón del corazón y del comentario no tengan ningún enlace? y para conseguirlo ¿puedes editar el html?

Comment: Si, al momento de clickear el corazon, y el comentario, no lleven al enlace

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si esto te va a servir porque puede que te hayan dicho que tengas que conseguirlo solo con jQuery, te pregunté en mi comentario si puedes editar el html y no me has respondido. Si puedes editar el html puedes conseguirlo fácilmente cerrando la etiqueta `a` después de la imagen, porque como lo tienes tú el enlace ocupa la imagen y los dos botones por lo que el enlace esta activo en todos sus hijos. Tu ejemplo sin usar jQuery cerrando el `a` después de la imagen:

```html
<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/04.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/04.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>


<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/05.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/05.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/06.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/06.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/07.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/07.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/08.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/08.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/09.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/09.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="meals__meal">
  <a href="../_assets/images/meal/10.jpg" class="meals__link">
    <img src="../_assets/images/meal/10.jpg" alt="Comida 01" class="meals__img">
    </a>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></button></li>
      <li class="social__element"><button class="social__btn social__like" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```